# integration by parts not giving the expected paper results? givoli2021

Tags: integration, matrices

I am trying to follow the derivation of the adjoint method derived in the paper "A tutorial on the adjoint method for inverse problems" by Dan Givoli, but I am stuck on trying to derive equation 16, in particular it is derived from equation 12 by integration by parts. The relevant part of equation 12 is:

$-\int_\Omega V_i w \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial k_A} \right)_{,i} d\Omega$

which by integration by parts should lead to the following term in equation 16:

$\int_\Omega V_i w_{,i} \frac{\partial u}{\partial k_A} d\Omega$

But I do not see how integration by parts can even be used in this case. The only thing I can think of doing here is to write out the sums in both instances (repeated indices are summed), but that doesn't seem to lead me anywhere closer to the result.

Does anyone have some insight?